# What is the difference between context layouts and the delta module?

Tags: 7, theming

I was recently introduced to the [Delta](http://drupal.org/project/delta) module and I think it is fantastic. Specifically the way it works with the [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega) theme in Drupal 7. It allows me to copy the theme settings and create layouts to load in [context](http://drupal.org/project/context) as a response. This is great, but as I went to enable the module on my system I ran across the context layouts module and am left wondering if I shouldn't just use the context layouts module.

So I am wondering if anyone can provide some insight into this. I will go ahead and check both out here in a minute, but I think they both do almost the same thing. I guess it really just depends on what restrictions on layout the context layouts module offers along with whether or not it can let me use the settings in the theme and modify those based on a context.

This also will be interesting to see if the delta module creates files or if it puts all of this into the DB. I suspect the latter, but am concerned about the former for packaging things up into features.

Comment: If you use omega you can import export settings using omega tools module.

Comment: Note that the question was for Omega 3.x (the Omega version at that time), and wouldn't make sense for Omega 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Delta module is not an alternative to Context Layouts, you should use them together.

- **Delta** allows you to create different versions of your Omega theme with different settings/layouts each.
- **Context Layouts** is part of the **Context** module, and will allow you to switch the different layouts you previously created with Delta, when a specific 'context' is active.

Comment: Thanks, I have since figured it out. But at least this is here for others. Points to you sir.

Comment: Here's a helpful explanation: [Control your Drupal Page Layout with Context and Delta](http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/control-your-drupal-page-layout-context-and-delta).